# Using user input in HTML form in realtime in HTML embedded Java code

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, servlets

I m working on a java severlet with Maven and Spring.

i need to create a table with a dynamic amount of rows. The rows shall be created with the variable "amountRows". So far my best guess is to create a static amount of rows with embedded java code and then hide them dynamicly with CSS / JavaScript.

Any idea how i could get rid of the "15" in the for-loop and replace it with the variable "amountRows"?

Alternatively any idea for a smoother solution?

```
 <form action="/myServlet/.../Page.html" method="post">
    <table>
    <caption><center><b>Table Title</b></center></caption>
        <tr><td><input type="number" min="00000" max="30" name="amountRows"/></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>column-title</td><td>column-title</td><td>column-title</td><td>column-title</td>
        </tr>
        <%  
            int i = 1;
            for(; i <= 15; i++) {
                out.print("<tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td");
            }
        %>          
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thymeleaf to do this. Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="container col-9">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th class="standard">Song Title and Artist</th>
                        <th class="year" style="font-weight:900">Year</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="song : ${songs}">
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" 
                                   th:href="@{/playsong(id=${song.songId})}"
                                   th:text="${song.title + ' - ' + song.artist}">
                                    Song title and artist
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="year" th:text="${song.year}">
                                Song year
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            &copy; Copyright 2020 Lindsay Nickalo. All rights reserved.
        </footer>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your mappings, you just add the variable to the model using `model.addAttribute("amountRows", amountRows);` and then it's available to use in the html with Thymeleaf. For my example, I passed in and entire list of Song objects, then used `th:each="song : ${songs}"` to make a table row for each song. In Thymeleaf, you reference variables using `${variable}`

In your POM, include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```